# Use CSS To hide an Element By its order?

Tags: css

I'm trying to use CSS to hide the list item "news" on the menu.
http://alexandriafilm.simpletix.com/Event/24/AIR/

something like

```
ul#menu li *(only 2nd instance)*
{
display:none;
}
```

Comment: Your example is inconsistent with the HTML in your page. There's no `<ul id="menu">`, only a `<div id="menu">`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case:

`#menu ul a:nth-child(2){display:none}`

Here is more info: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp